# Populate listview from database

Tags: android, database, listview, arraylist

hey guys i can currently fetch data from database into a table but im stuck with listview. my code is this to fetch all data:

```
public ArrayList<Object> getRowAsArray(long rowID)
{
    // create an array list to store data from the database row.
    // I would recommend creating a JavaBean compliant object 
    // to store this data instead.  That way you can ensure
    // data types are correct.
    ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Cursor cursor;

    try
    {
        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object store the information collected from the
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        cursor = db.query
        (
                TABLE_NAME,
                new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO, TABLE_ROW_THREE, TABLE_ROW_FOUR, TABLE_ROW_FIVE, TABLE_ROW_SIX, TABLE_ROW_SEVEN },
                TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                null, null, null, null, null
        );

        // move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
        // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(4));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(5));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(6));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(7));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return the ArrayList containing the given row from the database.
    return rowArray;
}
```

how would i populate this into a listview please. any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier than that - you don't even need to create an array list.

The "Adapter" is the key - the adapter is the interface between the list and your data. In your case, you want a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. There are examples for that in the Api Demos. Check it out.

You just pass it the cursor of your query, and it will automatically populate your listview with the data.

Comment: You know of any tutorial. I hav elooked but none to the type i needed. I have 7 rows in database to show

Comment: The API demos are very clearly structured. There is a group for "Lists", and in that there's one for "data from Cursor". Right here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List7.html

Comment: thanks mate. i have just had a look now, they seem to be using it for uris. Cursor cursor = managedQuery(getIntent().getData(), PROJECTION, null, null,
                                        NoteColumns.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

        // Used to map notes entries from the database to views
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.noteslist_item, cursor,
                new String[] { NoteColumns.TITLE }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        setListAdapter(adapter);   how would mine link to this. thanks mate

Comment: Same way. A cursor is a cursor. They use a ContentProvider, which is an abstraction of a database, you use the database directly. Doesn't matter. The final result is a Cursor, and that's what you plug into the SimpleCursorAdapter.